# Picture captured with front camera gets upside down

Tags: android, android-camera

I have  custom camera implementation in my project.
It works fine when I use the device's rear camera.
When capturing picture with front camera in portrait mode or reverse portrait mode, the image gets rotated upside down. In landscape mode, both cameras work fine.

I have implemented `SensorEventListener` and calculating the `orientation` value in `SensorChanged` callback so as to set `ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION` in the captured file.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {


                if (event.values[0] < 4 && event.values[0] > -4) {
                    if (event.values[1] > 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                        // UP
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90;
                    } else if (event.values[1] < 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                        // UP SIDE DOWN
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
                    }
                } else if (event.values[1] < 4 && event.values[1] > -4) {
                    if (event.values[0] > 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
                        // LEFT
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
                    } else if (event.values[0] < 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                        // RIGHT
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

The reason why I'm using `SensorEventListener` is because I am adding rotation animation to the icons present on the screen when the user rotates the screen .
Here is my `PictureCallback` :

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallBack = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            File pictureFile = new File(fileName);

            try {
                FileOutputStream purge = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                purge.write(data);
                purge.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            // Adding Exif data for the orientation.
            try {

                exif = new ExifInterface(fileName);
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, "" + orientation);
                exif.saveAttributes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

For debugging, when I `exif.setAttribute()` the  `orientation` value to `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90` in case it is  `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270` and vice-versa, it is working fine.
My question is what is the best and sure shot thing to resolve this so that it best fits to all the devices.

`Note :` I'm not using Bitmaps in this whole process. I'm writing the `data` into a file and sending it back to another activity to show the captured image.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few time ago. What I did was rotate the image taking care of the negative rotation of the device when you are using a frontal lense camera. So to convert your rotation you must do something like this:

```
  //check first in which camera we are
public boolean isFrontCamera(int cameraIndex) {
    try {
        if (mDeviceManager != null) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mDeviceManager.getCameraManager().getCameraCharacteristics(String.valueOf(cameraIndex));

            return characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
                    == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

  boolean mirror = isFrontCamera(Integer.parseInt(mCameraId));
                if (mirror) {
                    //Mirror image rotation is equal to the negative rotation of the device, but some external apps are not able to read negative numbers
                    //in image details, we do this to prevent the crash of this apps
                    rotation = 360 - rotation;
                    if (rotation == 360) {
                        rotation = 0;
                    }
                }
```

Later you must rotate your image before add it to your view, you can use a Matrix like this:

```
 public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap imageToOrient, int degreesToRotate) {
    Bitmap result = imageToOrient;
    try {
        if (degreesToRotate != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setRotate(degreesToRotate);
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    imageToOrient,
                    0,
                    0,
                    imageToOrient.getWidth(),
                    imageToOrient.getHeight(),
                    matrix,
                    true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.ERROR)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception when trying to orient image", e);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I know that you are not using a Bitmap, but you can modify the method to send it a byteArray or whatever you need.

Hope that it will help you a bit!
Best regards!